# Do I need to transform my money variable in decision tree analysis?

Tags: cart

If I believe my money variable (price of an item) does not have a linear relationship with interpreted user value/worth, should I transform it so that its split in the decision tree is based on a modified relationship between price:worth rather than tre linear one that I feel is incorrectly assumed?